# Use self in Swift class initializer without super

Tags: swift

Consider this class

```
class A {

  private let model: Model

  init() {
    self.model = Model(service: self)
  }
}
```

You can see that this will fail since I'm using `self` before everything is initialized. Since this is a pure swift class there is no option to call the `super` initializer.

How would you do this in pure swift without `NSObject` superclass, possibly without `lazy`?

Answer (score 3):

Essentially this looks wrong from design point of view. Your class `A` references `Model` and `Model` references `A`.

Logically, one of those two should be either optional variable (so that you can set it to `nil`), or a weak reference, otherwise you will have an ownership circle and a memory leak.

In other words, one of those two classes should be the owner of the other, you shouldn't have a mutual ownership.

Let's decide that the `Model` is the owned class, then:

```
class A {
   private let model: Model

   init() {
      let model = Model()
      self.model = model

      model.service = self
   }
}
```

Another option is to use the 2-phase initialization using an implicitly unwrapped optional

```
class A {
   private var model: Model!

   init() {
      self.model = Model(service: self)
   }
}
```